# How to add ellipsis for wider drop down items in Combo dropdown menu

Tags: java, swt

```
private Combo createDropdown(Composite parent) {

        Combo dropdown = new Combo(parent, SWT.DROP_DOWN | SWT.READ_ONLY);
        dropdown.setBackground(new Color(Display.getCurrent(), 106, 99, 95));
        dropdown.setSize(20, 20);
        this.stylingEngine = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IStylingEngine.class);
        stylingEngine.setClassname(dropdown, "TenatDropDownCombo");

        
        dropdown.setItems(dropDownItems);
        System.out.println("outside loop :" + availableTenantsNames);
        dropdown.select(currentTenantIndex);
```

I have written this code for creating a Combo dropdown, now I want to show the selected item with ellipsis if it is greater than the width of drop down.

How can I do the same?

I tried finding width of combo box but was not able. Can you suggest some approach?

Comment: Note: You should be using layouts rather than setSize on controls. Combos look very different on each platform, a size that looks right on Windows won't look right on Linux or macOS.

Comment: You can look at the `shortenText` methods in `org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolderRenderer` and also `org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.Hyperlink`. Both these require a `GC` set with the correct font. The exact width of the Combo drop down may vary between platforms and isn't easy to obtain.